# How to save the screenshots to maintain a good quality when uploading on android market?

Tags: android, screenshot, publishing

I just published an app on android market, I was very careful to create good looking screenshots, but after I saved them with photoshop and upload them on the application's page, the server compressed them into poor quality images...This is very frustrating... anyone knows a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

This might not contain a really great and simple answer but its something:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/10/android-market-featured-image.html

Answer (score 0):

Why use Photoshop? Just use the screenshot function in the emulator and they should be fine.

Comment: my application is made with flash builder and I took screenshots with another tool, but in the final all the images are cropped and saved at the best quality from photoshop. There must be something with the android compress process...

Answer (score 0):

The best way to take screenshots is:

- Run your project on an emulator in Eclipse
- Go to "Devices" window and click on "Screen capture"

These screenshots are the dimension your emulator is, so they are perfect for Market uploading and they won't be compressed